# Mapping non-alphanumeric symbols to macros

Tags: c

Is it possible to have the preprocessor turn something like `... this is my comment` into `// this is my comment`?

If not, is there it possible to put something in my `make` file to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the preprocessor only recognizes the same symbol set as C, which means macros has to start with either an underscore or a letter, followed by underscores, letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

With the C preprocessor: no, it recognizes the same kinds of tokens as C does; you can't introduce new ones.

With your own preprocessor: technically *yes*, but unless your preprocessor can accurately parse C and make sure that it only does the substitution in the exact right contexts, you will very likely run into problems where it accidentally corrupts your source. Besides, you will be creating an extra learning curve for new developers getting into the code. Overall, I wouldn't recommend it.